# Limit of ratio of integral

Tags: calculus, probability, limits

I want to show that:

$\underset{\alpha\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\; \frac{\int_0^x [F(y)]^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}dy}{[F(x)]^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}=0$

The function $F$ is a cumulative distribution function and $x$ is in the interior of the support of the function, so $F(y)\in[0,1)$ for all $y\in[0,x]$. $F$ is an increasing function and $F(x)>0$ at $x$. Also, $\alpha \in [0, 1]$.

The numerator and denominator both approach zero in the limit, but I need to show that the numerator approaches the limit faster than the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Let us write $t$ for $\frac  1 {\alpha}$.  Note that $\frac {\int_{x-\epsilon} ^{x} [F(y)]^{t}dt} {[F(x)]^{t}}\leq \epsilon$.  Now $\int_0^{x-\epsilon}  [F(y)]^{t}dt \leq [F(x-\epsilon)]^{t} (x-\epsilon)$. Since $x$ is in the interior of the support if $F$ it follows that $F(x-\epsilon ) <F(x)$. Rest is clear since $s^{t} \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ if $0 \leq s <1$ [Take $s=\frac {F(x-\epsilon)} {F(x)}$].

Comment: My understanding of what you have shown is that the fraction is always less than $x$. I agree that this would work if the support of $X$ was $[0,1]$, but it can be $[0,\infty)$ in this case.

Comment: @maccruiskeen See my edit,

Comment: okay got it now, thanks!